# What is the correct pattern for python findall function?

Tags: python, regex

Let's assume the we have the following text:

```
Aufstellung des Bebauungsplanes KLM-BP-025-2 „Neue   Hakeburg“, hier: Änderung des Aufstellungsbeschlusses vom 
13.12.2012 (DS-Nr. 164/12) – DS-Nr. 007/16/2 Der Beschluss DS-Nr. 164/12 vom 13.12.2012 zur Aufstellung  des Bebauungsplanes KLM-BP-025-2 „Neue Hakeburg“ wird ge- ändert. Der Bürgermeister wird beaufragt, für den in Anlage 1  abgegrenzten Geltungsbereich einen Bebauungsplan-Entwurf  erarbeiten zu lassen, mit dem die folgenden Punkte umgesetzt  werden: 1) Die zulässige Nutzungsart soll von „Sondergebiet 3 Hotel“  geändert werden
```

I would like to get all strings, that start with `Bebauungsplan` and end with '“'?

My attempt:

```
temps = re.findall(r'Bebauungsplan[\S\n ]+“', text, re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried your code, and how is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: it has `'\S'` and `' '` in the regex, which is actually opposite to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
temps = re.findall(r'Bebauungsplan[^“]+“', text)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/B9p2gy/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Bebauungsplan            'Bebauungsplan'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^“]+                    any character except: '“' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  “                        '“'
```